# C - Named pipe between top level process and bottom level (leaf) process

Tags: c, pipe, fork, ipc, named-pipes

I'm trying to write to a named pipe from a bottom level leaf process and read from the pipe on the top level process.

To do this, I'm first creating the FIFO in the top level process, then using a for loop to fork more processes. In the for loop I'm checking for leaf processes and if it's a leaf, I'm writing to the FIFO and breaking from the loop. Then, after the loop, I'm trying to read from the FIFO in the top level process. This isn't working, my program just gets stuck and stalls after the leaf process is created.

How can I send a message from a leaf back up to the top parent process through a FIFO?

CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MAX_BUF 1024

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    int numprocs = atoi(argv[1]);
    int lev = numprocs;
    fprintf(stdout,"ALIVE: Level %d process with pid=%d, child of ppid=%d.\n", lev, getpid(), getppid());

    //create shared memory
    const int SIZE = numprocs * sizeof(int);
    const char *name = "dleggio1OS";
    int shm_fd;
    int *ptr;
    shm_fd = shm_open(name, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);
    ftruncate(shm_fd, SIZE);
    ptr = mmap(0, SIZE, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);
    *ptr = getpid();

    //create fifo
    int fd;
    char *myfifo = "/tmp/dleggio1fifo";
    mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);

    //spawn procs
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i < numprocs; i++){
        lev--;
        int pfds[2];
        char buf[30];
        if(pipe(pfds) == -1){
            perror("pipe");
            exit(1);
        }
        pid_t pid;


        if((pid = fork()) < 0){
            perror("fork");
            exit(1);
        }

        if(pid == 0){ //child

            const int SIZE = numprocs * sizeof(int);
            const char *name = "dleggio1OS";
            int shm_fd;
            int *ptr;
            shm_fd = shm_open(name, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);
            ftruncate(shm_fd, SIZE);
            ptr = mmap(0, SIZE, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);
            ptr[i] = getpid();

            close(pfds[1]);
            if(read(pfds[0], buf, 3) <= 0){
                perror("child");
                exit(1);
            }
            int check = atoi(buf);
            fprintf(stdout,"ALIVE: Level %d process with pid=%d, child of ppid=%d.\n", check, getpid(), getppid());

            if(check == 1){ //leaf
                fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);
                write(fd,"leaf",sizeof("leaf"));
                close(fd);
                break;
            }

        }
        else{ //parent
            close(pfds[0]);
            char hold[3];
            sprintf(hold,"%d",lev);
            if(write(pfds[1], hold, 3) <= 0){
                perror("parent");
                exit(1);
            }

            wait(NULL);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    //read fifo
    char buff[MAX_BUF];
    fd = open(myfifo,O_RDONLY);
    read(fd,buff,MAX_BUF);
    close(fd);

    shm_unlink(name);
    unlink(myfifo);
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
ALIVE: Level 3 process with pid=554, child of ppid=451.
ALIVE: Level 2 process with pid=555, child of ppid=554.
ALIVE: Level 1 process with pid=556, child of ppid=555.
_ // <---- stalls here
```

Comment: Seeing the code would be helpful.

Comment: added code and output

Comment: The code (at least) provokes undefined behaviour by printing a non `0`-terminated "string" here: `printf("received %s message.\n",buff);`

Comment: Also the prototype for `ftruncate()` seems to be missing.

Comment: ... same for `wait()`.

Comment: @alk even without the print statement it still hangs

Comment: I also see the messages `received leaf message` and `received message` printed when compiling the above in gcc on ubuntu x86-64.

Comment: The code faces a race.

What would happen if the parent reads before the child had written?

Comment: You should really test `write()`/`reads()` results.

Comment: Changing the `break` statement in your leaf code to a `return 0;` almost seems to do what you're after.  But there are still several other problems as alk has pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

All processes are hung on a "wait()" call (i.e. waiting for one of its children to exit), except for the last child forked... which is hung on  "open(myfifo, O_WRONLY)".... 
The last child will continue to hang until a process opens the fifo for reading...

Comment: How can I make my top level process open the fifo for reading? If I put it after the for loop where I fork processes, the for loop never finishes (stuck on the last child) so it never reads. If I put it before the for loop, it tries to read before something writes to it and never executes the loop. If I try to read in the for loop in the parent part, other parents can read from it as well, not just the top parent.